# Can a fragment have an attribute?

Tags: reactjs, jsx, react-fragment

I have to set an attribute to the fragment. I want to do something like this:

```html
<className="name">
  abcd
</>
```

Is there any way to do like this?

Comment: [*"You can use `<></>` the same way you’d use any other element except that it doesn’t support keys or attributes."*](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html#short-syntax) Even with the non-shorthand syntax, per the same page, a fragment only supports a `key` attribute.

Comment: Thank you for your answer jonrsharpe!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't since it's React specific and not an HTML tag. Here is what the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html#short-syntax) say:

> You can use <></> the same way you’d use any other element except that
> it doesn’t support keys or attributes.